# OnClick event handler in DIVs (First OnClick affects all DIVs)

Tags: javascript, css, html, onclick

Basically I have three DIVs, and each DIV has an OnClick event handler inline. These OnClick events direct the user to whatever page the DIV is talking about specifically. This works, however, once all three DIVs have been coded with their onclick event, and separate URLs, the top most onclick event directs all three DIVs to the first URL. If I delete the code from the top most DIV, the second DIV directs to the second DIVs correct page, but the third DIV will direct to that page as well.

```
<div class="column_one" style="margin-top:25px;" onclick="location.href='/general-trades-contractor.php';">
<a href="/general-trades-contractor.php"><div class="column_one_image"></div></a>
<div class="white" class="row1"><h1> General Contractor </h1>
    <p class="left"></p><br><a href="/general-trades-contractor.php"><span>more...</span>
```

```
<div class="column_two" style="margin-top:25px;" onclick="location.href='/specialty-contractor.php';">
<a href="/specialty-contractor.php"><div class="column_two_image"></div></a>
<div class="white" class="row1"><h1 style="padding-left:20px;"> Specialty Contractor </h1>
    <p class="right"></p><br><a href="/specialty-contractor.php"><span style="padding-left:20px;">more...</span></a>
```

```
<div class="column_three" style="margin-top:25px;" onclick="location.href='/firestop-contractor.php';">
<a href="/firestop-contractor.php"><div class="column_three_image"></div></a>
<div class="white" class="row1"><h1> Firestopping Contractor </h1>
    <p class="left"></p><br><a href="/firestop-contractor.php"><span>more...</span></a>
```

As well as the relevant CSS.

```
.column_one
{   
display:block;
float:left;    
background-color:rgba(236,236,236,0.83);
height:250px;
width:940px;    
}

.column_two
{   
display:block;
float:left;    
background-color:rgba(236,236,236,0.83);
height:250px;
width:940px;    
}

.column_three
{   
display:block;
float:left;    
background-color:rgba(236,236,236,0.83);
height:250px;
width:940px;    
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your HTML is nested. Have a good day.

Comment: You have a `</div>` tag inside your `<a></a>` tag ??

Comment: @AlexW yes it works because it's an image (not shown).

Comment: @realianstanford I'm pretty sure that's always invalid HTML.

Comment: i don't know, even before I added the onclick command to the divs, that image was clickable, and loaded the page. @AlexW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is malformed, you are missing a closing `</div>` tag for each of your divs and a closing `</a>` tag for the second link.

if you run the html through a beautifier its easier to see:

```
<div class="column_one" style="margin-top:25px;" onclick="location.href='/general-trades-contractor.php';">
    <a href="/general-trades-contractor.php">
        <div class="column_one_image"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="white" class="row1">
        <h1>General Contractor</h1>
        <p class="left"></p>
        <br>
        <a href="/general-trades-contractor.php">
            <span>more...</span>
    </div>

    <div class="column_two" style="margin-top:25px;" onclick="location.href='/specialty-contractor.php';">
        <a href="/specialty-contractor.php">
            <div class="column_two_image"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="white" class="row1">
            <h1 style="padding-left:20px;">Specialty Contractor</h1>
            <p class="right"></p>
            <br>
            <a href="/specialty-contractor.php">
                <span style="padding-left:20px;">more...</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="column_three" style="margin-top:25px;" onclick="location.href='/firestop-contractor.php';">
            <a href="/firestop-contractor.php">
                <div class="column_three_image"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="white" class="row1">
                <h1>Firestopping Contractor</h1>
                <p class="left"></p>
                <br>
                <a href="/firestop-contractor.php">
                    <span>more...</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for not judging, it's such a simple mistake. This is just a small portion of the code I'm working on, and it was nearing the end of the day, tunnel vision I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing closing tags. Something like this:

```
<div class="column_one" style="margin-top:25px;" onclick="location.href='/general-trades-contractor.php';">
    <a href="/general-trades-contractor.php"><div class="column_one_image"></div></a>
    <div class="white" class="row1">
        <h1> General Contractor </h1>
        <p class="left"></p><br><a href="/general-trades-contractor.php"><span>more...</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should work. You were missing the last `</a></div></div>` and because of this every subsequent div was the child of the div above, thus the first div included second two, and second was the parent of third. So when you click the div, you actually trigger it's parent click.

Of course, you need to repeat this three times, for each `<div>` add `</a></div></div>` to close the elements.

Comment: Thank you for not judging, it's such a simple mistake. This is just a small portion of the code I'm working on, and it was nearing the end of the day, tunnel vision I guess. It's fixed now!